# What is difference to extend abstract class and non abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance

What is difference between abstract class and non abstract class when extending derived classes? Both class I didn't use the method overriding and abstract methods (i.e. abstract class). Just I inherited the properties. What and why did prefer the class?

Ex:

**Code 1:**

```
abstract class a {  
    protected int empnno; 
    protected String empname; 
} 

class b extends a { 
    ...
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
class a {  
    protected int empnno; 
    protected String empname; 
}

class b extends a { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

> ***what is difference to extend abstract class and non abstract class?***

Abstract classes **may have abstract methods**. Abstract methods are methods without implementations and these *must* be implemented by your subclass (unless you make your subclass abstract too).

Since your `a` class have no abstract methods, there is no difference what so ever from a subclass-perspective. (The *only* difference is that if `a` is abstract it may no longer be instantiated as is. It may only be instantiated in terms of subclasses.)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there is a class B, and class A, where A extends be. The following are the possible scenarios:

```
1. B is abstract

1.1. B doesn't have abstract methods

1.1.1. A is abstract

1.1.1.1. You don't want to instantiate A. Everything is fine.

1.1.1.2. You want to instantiate A. That's not possible, you can't create abstract objects

1.1.2. A is not abstract. Everything is fine

1.2. B has at least an abstract method

1.2.1. A is abstract

1.2.1.1. You don't want to instantiate A. Everything is fine.

1.2.1.2. You want to instantiate A. That's not possible, you can't create abstract objects

1.2.2. A is not abstract

1.2.2.1. A doesn't implement all the abstract methods. You can't run your project until you change this

1.2.2.2. A implements all the abstract methods. Everything is fine.

2. B is not abstract

2.1. A is abstract

2.1.1. You want to instantiate A. Error.

2.1.2. You don't want to instantiate A. No problem

2.2. A is not abstract. No problem.
```

Answer (score 2):

To have a better understanding, we can compare **Abstract Classes** with **Interfaces**, the **main differences** are:

1. While abstract classes may contain fields/properties and concrete
   methods, interfaces may contain only abstract methods (method
   signatures).
2. One class can implement several interfaces, whereas it can extend just one class, abstract or not.

Therefore, when you create a subclass extended an abstract class, you need to implement the abstract method that was in the abstract class(if any), otherwise, the subclass would be still an abstract class -- which cannot be instantiated!!

Also, you can use interfaces instead of abstract classes if you only want to declare some methods signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Actually they are the same, but you cannot instanciate Abstract classes. So if you want nobody tries to instanciate your class, you would like to make it Abstract.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class will contain abstract methods that do not have an implementation.

When you extend this class, sometimes you may decide only to provide implementations for some of those abstract methods. In this case you've extended an abstract class and yet the subclass is still abstract.

If you implement all the abstract methods, your subclass is typically not abstract (although there's nothing stopping you from declaring it as such, AFAIK).

Comment: *An abstract class will contain abstract methods that do not have an implementation.* -- No, not necessarily.